# Java open outlook and fill subject and body

Tags: java, outlook

I try to open Outlook, create a new mail and fill out cc, to, subject and body
So far, it opens outlook and fill the fields for to and cc.
Subject and body works only, if it contains a single word.
If there is a space, java will complain about illegal character in URL
I tried to encode the URL but in this case all spaces will be shown with a + in Outlook.
I tried manually to replace the space with %20 but it will show %20 in Outlock.

```
            String subject  = "This is the subject";// %20
            String body     = "Dear colleagues this is a";
            String to       = "mail1@xxx.com";
            String cc       = "mail2@xxx.com;mail3@xxx.com";

            try {
                subject = URLEncoder.encode(subject, "UTF-8");
                body = URLEncoder.encode(body, "UTF-8");
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e2) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e2.printStackTrace();
            }
                
                
            try {
                Desktop.getDesktop().mail( new URI( "mailto:" + to + "?subject=" + subject + "&cc=" + cc + "&body=" + body) );
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (URISyntaxException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Microsoft® Outlook® für Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2302 Build 16.0.16130.20684) 64 Bit

I dont want to send the mail direct with JAVA.

Comment: Can you log what gets passed to `new URI()`?

Comment: If I use 

`URLEncoder.encode(subject, "UTF-8");`

I will get

`mailto:mail1@xxx.com?subject=This+is+the+subject&cc=mail2@xxx.com;mail3@xxx.com&body=Dear+colleagues+this+is+a`

Comment: Don’t use URLEncoder for this;  that class is for submitting HTML form data.  The URI class properly encodes URI parts, so use `new URI("mailto", to + "?subject=" + subject + "&cc=" + cc + "&body=" + body, null)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don’t use URLEncoder for this;  that class is for submitting HTML form data.  From [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/net/URLEncoder.html):

> Utility class for HTML form encoding. This class contains static methods for converting a String to the application/x-www-form-urlencoded MIME format.

For encoding a URI, just use any of [the URI constructors](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/net/URI.html#constructor-summary) which take more than one argument.  (The single-argument constructor, by design, expects percent-escapes to already be present.)

In your case, since mailto URIs are not hierarchical URIs, use the [three-argument constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/net/URI.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String)) that expects a general “scheme-specific part”:

```
Desktop.getDesktop().mail(
    new URI("mailto", to + "?subject=" + subject + "&cc=" + cc + "&body=" + body, null));
```

One word of caution:  the above won’t work if any of the mail information contains `&`.  In that case, you’ll have to do the work yourself.  Fortunately, it’s not so hard:

```
Formatter preenc = new Formatter();
Consumer<String> encoder = s -> {
    for (byte b : s.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {
        boolean unsafe = (b <= 32 || b >= 127 ||
            "<>#%\"{}|\\^[]`?&=".indexOf(b) >= 0);
        preenc.format(unsafe ? "%%%02x" : "%c", b);
    }
};

preenc.format("%s", "mailto:");
encoder.accept(to);
preenc.format("%s", "?subject=");
encoder.accept(subject);
preenc.format("%s", "&cc=");
encoder.accept(cc);
preenc.format("%s", "&body=");
encoder.accept(body);

URI uri = new URI(preenc.toString());
```

Answer (score -1):

you can simply replace like below it works,

subject = URLEncoder.encode(subject, "UTF-8");

body = URLEncoder.encode(body, "UTF-8");

subject = subject.replaceAll("\\+", "%20");

body = body.replaceAll("\\+", "%20");